# Configuration file in .net windows application

Tags: c#

I am new in .net.

I am actually converting a Console application into Windows application in .net. And I want to include some configuration files in the windows application.

I know that for web application there is Web.config and for Console application there is App.config to have the configuration details.

But I don't have any ideas about the configuration file in windows application. I have to include the configuration details in my windows application that included in the console application that i want to convert.

**UPDATE**

Problem Fixed.

It is a fault from my part. I also copied `startup` tag. Can anyone please tell me for what this tag.??

Thant you all for the replay.

Comment: i think it will be same app.config

Comment: when i did so BadImageException caught!!

Comment: BadImageException is usually a 32/64-bit problem. i.e. you try to load a 32-bit dll in a 64-bit application and vice versa

Comment: The `startup` tag indicates which framework to use. If you try to force an application made for .NET 4.0 to run with .NET 2.0, you may get the error you described.

Answer (score 3):

A windows application is a WinForms or WPF application and use the same App.Config renamed in `yourappname.exe.config` as in Console Applications. So just go on with that

An excellent series of articles on configuration files (I will dare to say `the reference`)
[Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

Comment: It will work if the project and the namespaces are named the same as in the console application. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar not sure to understand you correctly. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Well, the `app.config` file contains a section `<applicationSettings>` (or `<userSettings>`) for the settings. These sections contain another section that's named after the global namespace, for example `MyTest_Application.Properties.Settings`. It can also contain more than one section, for example one for a referenced DLL also. In the header, there's an entry for each section. So only if the new application uses the same namespaces as the old application you can re-use the old configuration file.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar oh yes I was thinking about a new app not to a porting of the old one. And yes, you have definitely pointed out an hurdle that the OP should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the project's properties and change to the "Settings" tab. You might see a message that no settings file is present right now. If you click the link, one will be created.

Add one setting as a dummy so that all sections in the `app.config` file are created (`<applicationSettings>` or `<userSettings>` and the respective section for your namespace). Then, open the original config file in a text edit, copy the settings lines (*not* the lines containing the `<namespace.properties.settings>` start and end tags) and then paste them into the new `app.config`. Make sure that you copy application settings to the `<applicationSettings>` section and user settings to the `<userSettings>` sections accordingly.

The next time you open the Settings tag, you'll be asked whether you'd like to import the new settings.

Answer (score 2):

There’s a really simple way to do this.. simply go to the File \ Add New Item menu, or hit Ctrl+Shift+A

[image]

You’ll notice that it’s already set to App.config for you. Just hit the Open button.

If you look in the Solution Explorer, you will see that the config file is in your project:

Now build your application, and take a look in the \bin\debug\ folder. You’ll see that the configuration file has automatically been generated and named correctly for your executable:

[image]

Reference taken from **[HERE](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/how-to-add-a-configuration-file-to-your-windows-forms-application/)**

Comment: Nooo! Use Properties > Settings!

Comment: I am getting BadImageException
Could not load file or assembly 'AmazonAdavancedPayemtnWindowsTest.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: @nabu i think you are get this error when you are building the application .. right ??

Comment: Nop.Building succcessfully. The exception is getting when running the project.

Comment: BadImageException arises because you have made an AnyCpu or x86 app and trying to call a 64 assembly on a 32bit OS. Check your references.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project go to -->Add --> New Item and then you will find a dialog as shown

[image]